# start redis-server on debian/ubuntu boot

Tags: redis, docker, debian, startup

I am trying to create a docker container where redis starts at boot.
there will be other foreground services running on that other container which will connect to the redis db.

for some reason the service does not start when i run the container.
here my simplified Dockerfile

```
FROM debian

# this solves an issue described here:
# http://askubuntu.com/questions/365911/why-the-services-do-not-start-at-installation
RUN sed -i -e s/101/0/g /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

# install redis-server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y redis-server

# updates init script (redundant)
RUN update-rc.d redis-server defaults 

# ping google to keep the container running in foreground
CMD ["ping", "google.com"]
```

can anybody explain me why this is not working and how this should be done right?

Comment: Why not just use the redis image from Docker Hub? At least look at it to understand how it works. But the issue is that you never start the redis server...

Comment: because i need to run other stuff on the container. redis should be just a background service. redis should start at boot by my understandings if i add it as a service to run at boot. and the script is in `/etc/rc2.d` and links to `/etc/init.d/redis-server` which works fine if i run it manually.

Comment: If you want a process to sit in the foreground forever, in the future try something like `cat` instead of sending out a continuous stream of pings over the Internet to a third party for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a docker container is *like* a full OS but has some key differences. It's not going to run a full init system. It's designed and intended to run a single process tree. While you can run a supervisor such as runit et al within a container, you are really working against the grain of docker and all the tooling and documentation is going to lead you away from using containers like VMs and toward the harmony of 1 process/service per container.

So redis isn't starting because the `ping` command is literally the only process running in your container.

> there will be other foreground services running on that other container which will connect to the redis db.

Don't do it this way. Really. Everything will be easier when you put 1 process in each container and connect them via network links.

Comment: i see and i get your point, but this was the reason why i wanted to run this on just one container instead of having every single bit of the application as a separate container. this redis process wont do much and to me it will be a little wasteful to start a separate container just for redis.

Comment: Wasteful is highly debatable. Containers are cheap - very similar to processes in cost. But in any case, the "use containers like mini VMs" camp is mostly led by the Phusion folks, so look here for docs on running a process supervisor inside your container: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker

Comment: i run my containers on joyent triton so cheap is a $ amount and not a question of resources. in any case i found an easy way to do what i need to do. ill take a look at the link.  thx

Answer (score 0):

Digging up an old question here, but I landed on it whilst trying to package a *really* simple Redis job queue into an existing docker image setup. I needed it to start up on image boot so the app could have access to it. Memory and performance are not a concern in this scenario or an external Redis server would absolutely be the right choice.

Here's what I did in my `Dockerfile` for a simple NodeJs app to make it work without editing any system files post-install:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y redis-server
CMD service redis-server start & node dist/src/main
```

Sort of crude using parallel command processes, but as the accepted answer points out this is *not* a real operating system so we really only care about Redis being online when the app is.